# Trying to run jupyter notebook on ec2 machine which sits on a bastion host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have my ec2 machine which sits behind a bastion host and I'm trying to run jupyter notebook on my ec2 machine.

I'm SSHing into my ec2 machine through a bastion IP and have installed anaconda on my ec2 machine. This ec2 machine I have doesn't have a public IP, has only a private IP. Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can SSH into it, you can tunnel HTTP and access your jupyter notebooks securely. Try something like:

```
ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:80 ec2-user@ec2-address
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm able to run the service on my ec2 machine but I'm not able to run the notebook on my local machine. How do I access the jupyter service running on my ec2 (running behind a bastion), also the ec2 machine has no public IP, it only has private IP.

Comment: @DocZenith Did you ever figure this out? I just encountered the same problem today. I previously managed to get an ssh tunnel thru a bastion to a redshift cluster which is very similar. I believe the command might be something like `ssh -f -N -L 127.0.01:8888:127.0.0.1:8888 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $user@$bastion_dns`, but it's the end of the day and I'm testing tomorrow.